# Celery Beat cannot connect to Rabbitmq container

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, rabbitmq, celery

My celery beat docker container has (from what I believe) problems connecting the message broker.

I have a RabbitMQ container running:

```
....
rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3.11.13-management-alpine
    container_name: 'rabbitmq'
    ports:
      - 5672:5672
      - 15672:15672
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      - ./data:/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia
    networks:
      - rabbitmq_go_net
....
```

And a Python container running a Django application with Celery (there are multiple more containers running the backend itself, celery workers, celery beat and celery flower, which all utilize the same backend files but handle different tasks):

```
....
celery-beat:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/local/django/Dockerfile
    container_name: 'beat'
    image: beat
    command: ["./wait-for-it.sh", "0.0.0.0:1337", "--", "/start-celerybeat"]
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    env_file:
      - .env
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq
      - backend
    restart: always
....
```

Starting script for celery beat `start.sh` (executed by /start-celerybeat):

```bash
#!/bin/bash
    
set -o errexit
set -o nounset
  
rm -f './celerybeat.pid'
celery -A app beat -l INFO
```

app/celery.py:

```py
from __future__ import absolute_import
import os
    
from celery import Celery
from celery.schedules import crontab
    
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'app.settings')
    
app = Celery('app')
    
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
    
app.autodiscover_tasks()#(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
    
@app.on_after_configure.connect
def setup_periodic_tasks(sender, **kwargs):
    ....
```

app/settings.py

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ....
    'django_celery_results',
    'django_celery_beat',
    ....
]

CELERY_BROKER_URL = CONFIG.get('CELERY_BROKER_URL')
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = CONFIG.get('CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND')
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULER = "django_celery_beat.schedulers:DatabaseScheduler"
```

.env

```
RABBITMQ_USER=user
RABBITMQ_PASSWORD=password
RABBITMQ_PORT=5672
RABBITMQ_HOST=rabbitmq
CELERY_BROKER_URL=amqp://${RABBITMQ_USER}:${RABBITMQ_PASSWORD}@localhost:${RABBITMQ_PORT}/${RABBITMQ_HOST}
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND=amqp://
```

I receive the following error when starting up my `docker-compose`:

```
beat         | [2024-02-20 15:19:54,198: ERROR/MainProcess] beat: Connection error: [Errno 111] Connection refused. Trying again in 6.0 seconds...
beat         | [2024-02-20 15:20:00,212: ERROR/MainProcess] beat: Connection error: [Errno 111] Connection refused. Trying again in 8.0 seconds...
beat         | [2024-02-20 15:20:08,223: ERROR/MainProcess] beat: Connection error: [Errno 111] Connection refused. Trying again in 10.0 seconds...
beat         | [2024-02-20 15:20:18,235: ERROR/MainProcess] beat: Connection error: [Errno 111] Connection refused. Trying again in 12.0 seconds...
beat         | [2024-02-20 15:20:30,248: ERROR/MainProcess] beat: Connection error: [Errno 111] Connection refused. Trying again in 14.0 seconds...
beat         | [2024-02-20 15:20:44,265: ERROR/MainProcess] beat: Connection error: [Errno 111] Connection refused. Trying again in 16.0 seconds...
beat         | [2024-02-20 15:21:00,283: ERROR/MainProcess] beat: Connection error: [Errno 111] Connection refused. Trying again in 18.0 seconds...
beat         | [2024-02-20 15:21:18,307: ERROR/MainProcess] beat: Connection error: [Errno 111] Connection refused. Trying again in 20.0 seconds...
```

If you need more information than that, feel free to ask what more you need specifically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `CELERY_BROKER_URL` is wrong. In Docker `localhost` means local loopback network interface within the same docker container.

**Try this instead:**

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL=amqp://${RABBITMQ_USER}:${RABBITMQ_PASSWORD}@rabbitmq:5672/
```

For more information you can check this post: [From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach)

Comment: I tried your solution but now I receive `[2024-02-20 17:38:08,150: ERROR/MainProcess] beat: Connection error: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution. Trying again in 8.0 seconds...`

Comment: Provide your `docker-compose.yml` details

Comment: I fixed the error from the comment above by adding all my containers to the same network. Now there's a different error but that one doesn't have anything to do with this thread.